# Why is number of hard links for a directory 2 + the number of subdirectories?

Tags: bash, unix, command-line, hardlink

When using `ls -l`, I noticed that directories start with 2 hard links, and gain one for each subdirectory. I understand that the current directory link `.` counts as one link and the parent directory link `..` of each subdirectory counts as a hard link, but:

1. Why don't subfiles count towards hard links when subdirectories do?
2. Why does the parent directory link `..` count as a hard link for both this directory *and* the parent directory?

Comment: This post is a little confusing because you can't hard-link directories, only files.  `.` and `..` are not hard links.

Comment: "Why" questions aren't on topic here. The answer to this won't improve how you practice software development; it's just historical trivia. Consider [unix.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the following directory tree

```
/a
  /b
    /c
    /d
```

Then directory `b` at path `/a/b` has 4 hard links. The links are the following:

- `b` (from the parent directory)
- `.` (from the directory itself)
- `c/..`
- `d/..`

Files don't count against the link count of a directory, because files do not have a nested `..` directory, thus do not point back to the directory.

We can calculate the number of hardlinks for each directory shown above:

- a: 3

  - `a` (from `/`)
  - `.`
  - `b/..`
- c: 2

  - `c` (from b)
  - `.`
- d: 2

  - `d` (from b)
  - `.`